# Dummy RSS feed in wordpress widgets

Tags: wordpress, rss, widget, feed

I'm putting a little wordpress site together but when it's done my 'client' wants to include an RSS feed to load news and such in a widget. Now I would like to test this, because I have never done this before.

I don't have the RSS feed from the client yet because it doesn't exist yet. Is there a way to get 'dummy' content for an RSS feed? I have tried searching google but haven't found anything. Am I naming this 'dummy' feed wrong or is there no such thing as a dummy feed?

Can I just get the rss feed of a random site? Or do I have to own the site to find the RSS feed url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sites, like [cnn.com](http://edition.cnn.com/services/rss/), has rss feeds for news. You can choose what type of feeds you want to add to your theme. Once you have a url,

- [Add/Register a Sidebar to your theme.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Sidebars)
- On your admin dashboard, go to Appearance/Widgets & Add RSS Widget.
- Then just paste the url of the rss feed.

Hope this helps.